# Angular and Asp.net core CORS issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have had this issue for some time now and I have tried every possible solution for it, my asp.net core server has CORS enabled, code as follow, but sometimes I get this error of No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

My Production API is hosted on IIS on windows server

Is there any way i can get this debugged?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'Production_API' from origin 'DOMAIN' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone.js:3372

GET APICALL net::ERR_FAILED

in zone.js this is where it says it has a error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

```
 sendNative.apply(target, data.args);
 target[XHR_SCHEDULED] = true;
 return task;
```

ASP.net Core CORS Code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowEverything",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(
          option =>
          {
              option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          })
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
           options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
           options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
           options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]));
           options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
           options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"];
       });
    

       

        services.AddTransient<Services.IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.Configure<SMSoptions>(Configuration);
```

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

```
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });

        IMapper _mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(_mapper);
    }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       app.UseCors("AllowEverything");
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            //app.UseHsts();
        }




        app.UseCors("AllowEverything");


        app.UseAuthentication();
        
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
     }
```

Comment: I'm missing the middleware configuration for `app.UseCors(...)` in your question. It matters, because the order in which the middlewares are declared is the order in which they are handled. Often, exception handling (pages) are declared before the cors middleware and it results in missing cors headers for error responses.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention that, i am using app.UseCors("AllowEverything");

Comment: Can you show us what other middlewares you have in exactly the order that you have it in your code?

Comment: i am not using any other middleware!

Comment: Then how does your application work? I'm interested to know why you would use `AddMvc()` but then don't add the middleware for it like `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseMvc()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand that, i have added it to my code
Thank

Comment: So I guess in your real code you have `app.UseCors(...)` after the developer exception page, and not twice as you have shown now, right? That is a common setup scenario from the template and examples. Problem is, when there is an exception, cors won't hit, because it is after that setting. That is *a* reason why you might be seeing cors errors instead of probably an exception in your client.

Comment: oh okay, I get that, I will put cors above exception and try it out that way, Thank you very much :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0
i coppied it from here, even here they have it after develop exceptions.

Comment: It is not really clear and they should emphasize this, but it says: _The following code applies a CORS policy to all the app's endpoints with the specified origins_. So I guess they should emphasize 'endpoints' as in `UseEndPoints`. In that example static files also falls outside of the cors scope.

Comment: I tried a lot of different solution, in the end I found there is a unknown error on http interceptor and what I think is that when System is maxed at the CPU usage then this happens, as angular isn't able to complete the call and it goes into unknown error as CPU has no room to work on it. Please let me know if that makes sense or something that can happen with heavy applications.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of different solution, in the end I found there is a unknown error on http interceptor and what I think is that when System is maxed at the CPU usage then this happens, as angular isn't able to complete the call and it goes into unknown error as CPU has no room to work on it.
Please let me know if that makes sense or something that can happen with heavy applications.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`AllowAnyOrigin()` is only valid when not using `AllowCredentials()`

You have to use `.WithOrigins("http://example.com","http://www.contoso.com");` when using credentials.

Also do you use `app.UseCors(AllowEverything);` in your

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

Comment: app.UseCors("AllowEverything");
yes i am using that

Comment: Okay, so if i take out AllowCredentails it will fix that?
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try x is the policy :

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:****"));
```